# Sens de « que veux-tu ? » dans un contexte particulier

Tags: sens

Dans le passage suivant on trouve la question « que veux tu ? », apparemment une question tout à fait banale et que je comprends de façon intuitive par force de contact répété à la lecture sans jamais avoir approfondi l'idée : ce n'est pas une demande stricte d'information sur ce qui pourrait être désiré, c'est une énonciation qui a une toute autre signification, ce dont on peut être sûr.

> Casse-cou! La mort vient. Elle vient pour tous les peuples : c'est une affaire de siècles. Vas-tu faire fi des siècles? La vie tout entière est une affaire de jours. Il faut être de sacrés diables d'abstracteurs, pour se placer dans l'absolu, au lieu d'étreindre l'instant qui passe. Que veux-tu? La flamme brûle la torche. On ne peut pas être et avoir été, mon pauvre Christophe.

Quelqu'un pourrait-il/elle nous faire part de la meilleure façon ou même de ce qu'il/elle croit être une bonne façon d'expliquer ce sens ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Que veux-tu ?* ou les variantes *qu'est-ce que tu veux* ou *que voulez-vous* sont des questions réthoriques courantes dans une conversation, pour exprimer un sentiment de résignation face à une situation qui ne peut être changée.
On peux comprendre cette question comme un forme courte de "veux-tu vraiment essayer de changer une situation qui ne peut l'être ?"

Un exemple fictif:

> -J'ai reçu une amende de 50 euros, j'étais mal garé.
>
> -Que veux-tu ? C'est la loi, mon pauvre ami...

Comment: Good answer…would it be too much asking to supply an alternative formulation in the passage, something in plain, matter of fact language?

Comment: I had not seen I had answered in Engish whereas your question was in French, sorry... Which part would you like to have rephrased ?

Comment: As I think of it again, it seems that "veux-tu vraiment essayer de changer une situation qui ne peut l'être ?" can do, never mind, unless you are inspired by something that seems interesting to you; of course the "que veux-tu" part is what I'd like to see paraphrased as expressively as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ce pourrait être "Qu'est-ce que tu veux que je fasse?" (verbe faire). En anglais, "What can I do?".

Comment: That's it, with a tiny alteration: "Qu'est-ce que tu veux que j'y fasse?". Otherwise, the sentence could never be fitted into this context. What could be supposed is that the short form comes from this longer enonciation; I guess that's what you mean…